# Problem with SwiftUI DatePicker animation

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

I'm trying to create a Wheel date picker style that will animate in from the bottom of the screen when a button is clicked, however the animation seems to lag when the date picker moves and it looks awful.

Is there anything I could add to help the animation look smoother. I've tested this code on the simulator and my device and both seem to have the same issue.

```
struct datepicker: View {
    @State private var date = Date()
    @State private var shown: Bool = false
    @State private var isHidden = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("toggle",action:{
                shown.toggle()
            })
            DatePicker("", selection: $date)
                .labelsHidden()
                .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
                .offset(y: shown ? 500:0)
                .animation(.linear)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually there's no need to use `offset` in SwiftUI. Here you can rely on the `.transition(.move(edge: .bottom))` when the view is added/removed from the view:

```
struct datepicker: View {
    @State private var date = Date()
    @State private var shown: Bool = false
    @State private var isHidden = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("toggle", action: {
                shown.toggle()
            })
            ZStack {
                DatePicker("", selection: .constant(Date()))
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
                    .opacity(0)
                if shown {
                    DatePicker("", selection: $date)
                        .labelsHidden()
                        .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
                        .animation(.linear)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I added an extra hidden `DatePicker` so other controls don't change their position during transition.)